# Automating SSL certificate creation & deployment für WCF Service

Tags: wcf, ssl, installation

we have developed an application which is backed by a WCF service which uses a self signed SSL certificate. Now we want to improve the deployment of our application. As of now, when we install the application we have to go through several steps to create a Certificate Authority, create a certificate (with makecert.exe) and register the certificate with an SSL port via httpcfg / netsh. Whats the best way to automate this process? Should I just script all those actions together?

Comment: You're talking about self-signed certs and then of creating your CA and issuing certs. Which of both are you actually using (or is it about deploying in production)? You'd normally create only one CA for a given institution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Scrip them and once you have scripts you can run them from installation package.